# How to get json response of third party domain using jsonp or jquery.getjson

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to this web programming.I want to get json response of third party domain in javascript.So that I tried with Ajax http request but it is only for same domain.So that I am trying using jsonp and jquery.getjson.Still I am not getting any result please help me.

code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>get json in alert</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("http://cricketapi.mblogi.com/sfsjson.php?callback=?", function(result){
   //response data are now in the result variable
   alert(result);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it depends on whether the remote resource supports jsonp, in your it doesn't look so...

Comment: one easy solution is to write a proxy yourself.... where you sent a request to your web server which then makes a request to the target resource and sents back the response to client

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure that the URL you are using is returning data in json format.

For example, updating your code to access a Flickr feed:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?ids=8623220@N02&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(result){
   //response data are now in the result variable
   alert(result);
});
```

The key here is at the end of the URL, `&format=json&jsoncallback=?` which tells the Flickr server to send back json data.

So the solution for you is to update the URL.

Comment: I tried with flicker it is working but when I try with my url it is not working .Have you tried?

Comment: my url is giving json response .you can also try  http://cricketapi.mblogi.com/sfsjson.php

Comment: you may need to update the php file with appropriate functions to handle the request. im not sure how to do that however.

Comment: i tried with whatever origins site .It is giving response